# How to hide database table primary ID in ASP.NET Routes?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I am using asp.net routes for the first time.  Here is something I am trying to achieve.

Registered routes in global.asax file

```
routes.MapPageRoute("HelpEditRoute", "Help/{action}/{id}", "~/ad/Help.aspx")
```

This code inside Help.aspx

```
Response.Redirect("~/Help/Edit/12")
```

In code behind page of say help.aspx I am doing a redirect to following url to edit article number 12.  Here ID is the database table primary key ID.

**Problem**: I don't want to show database primary key(ID) into browser address bar.  Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: How will you identify what you have to edit if you don't have the PK in the URL? Do you have any other field that uniquely identifies records?

Comment: It will be primary key but my concern is with security.  Is that ok to expose it in the url?  And does stackoverflow on their pages use PK?  I am sorry for too many questions.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: You should know that you are redirecting incorrectly, if you need to change the location of that page internally, all of your response.redirects will break. If you're using routes you should use `Response.RedirectToRoute("HelpEditRoute");.` That's one, if not the reason it asks you to specify a "route name" when creating a new route.

Comment: @Mitul: users should not be able to do any harm just by knowing a PK. If they can, you're in trouble :)

Comment: @Nick - But what could be done to edit a particular post. Isn't it we have give full route.

Comment: @Mitul, ah my apologies, if the route contains a parameter(query string ` `RedirectToRoute` has an overload that accepts more than one argument like `Response.RedirectToRoute("HelpEditRoute", new {id= someId});` You may need to specify the action too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oftentimes this is referred to as a url slug. And, in manageable scenarios (eg NOT stack overflow which generates URL slugs AND exposes the primary key), it is easy to add a user-generated, uniquely indexed field to your table to handle this. Code-wise, if you stick with the default routing conventions, you just lookup based on the surrogate key (slug) you just created rather than the primary key.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks Barnett.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to get around showing the ID in the url is to encrypt the ID (one example: [How to Encrypt Query String Parameters in ASP.NET | Keyvan Nayyeri](http://nayyeri.net/how-to-encrypt-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net)), there are a multitude of ways to encrypt an ID then decrypt on the server side.

Another method is to use GUIDs as a key to your DB record and use the GUID in your URL